# Get Server Name from server path from sql table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get server name from string inside column.
ex

```
 CREATE TABLE #Sample(ServerPath varchar(50))
    GO
    INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) VALUES ('\\TestServer1\Test')
    INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) VALUES ('\\TestServer2\Test')
    INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) VALUES ('\\TestServer3\Test')
INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) VALUES ('TestServer4)
    SELECT * FROM #Sample 
    GO
    DROP TABLE #Sample`enter code here`
```

I want output like string in between double slash to first single slash

```
TestServer1  
TestServer2   
TestServer3
```

what sql command to execute or regular expression in sql which give me expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't need to be regex (as per your tag). Just use something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample(ServerPath varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) 
VALUES 
('\\TestServer1\Test')
,('\\TestServer2\Test')
,('\\TestServer3\Test')

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ServerPath,3,CHARINDEX('\',ServerPath,3)-3) Result
FROM #Sample 

Result
TestServer1
TestServer2
TestServer3
```

This is assuming that it always starts with double backslash

If you've got data without backslashes then use this to check first;

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample(ServerPath varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #Sample (ServerPath) 
VALUES 
('\\TestServer1\Test')
,('\\TestServer2\Test')
,('\\TestServer3\Test')
,('TestServer4')

SELECT 
CASE
   WHEN CHARINDEX('\\',ServerPath) = 0
      THEN ServerPath
   ELSE SUBSTRING(ServerPath,3,CHARINDEX('\',ServerPath,3)-3)
END Result
FROM #Sample 
GO
DROP TABLE #Sample

Result
TestServer1
TestServer2
TestServer3
TestServer4
```

Comment: Hi @Rich, Thank u, but it gives me following errer. "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."

Comment: Do you have any data that doesn't have backslashes in it? Also, any data that doesn't start with a double backslash?

Comment: Yes, I have some data like D:\TestFolder in same column

Comment: I've updated the answer, it now checks if the string contains a double backslash before doing the substring function. If it doesn't contain that string it's just going to return the field without modification.